# AJAX post string array to webapi 2

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is my ajax call:

```
var myIds = ["A","B","C"]
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: /DoStuffAndThings?year=2018&name=test,
    data: {myIds: myIds},
    traditional: false
});
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoStuffAndThings(int year, string name, [FromBody] List<string> myIds) {
    // do stuff
}
```

year and name come through without issue but myIds is always empty.

Ive tried

`data: {myIds: myIds}` and `data: myIds` and `data: {"": myIds}` and I tried using `Ienumerable<string>` and `List<string>`  and `string[]`

and I've tried traditional: true and false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model binder is unable to parse the send data as it does not know the format

Use `JSON.stringify` along with the corresponding parameters

```
var myIds = ["A","B","C"];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DoStuffAndThings?year=2018&name=test",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data:JSON.stringify(myIds),
    traditional: false
});
```

The model binder should then be able to recognize the string collection in the body of the request.

Comment: This works when i specify the contentType and dataType

Answer (score 0):

When sending data to a web server, the data has to be a string.
Convert a JavaScript object into a string with JSON.stringify().

Before data, use `JSON.stringify(myIds)`.

```
 var myIds = ["A","B","C"]
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'json',
       url: /DoStuffAndThings?year=2018&name=test,
       data: JSON.stringify(myIds),
       traditional: false
 });
```